# IOException java problem

Tags: java

I'm working through the Head First Java book, and one piece of code it makes me write looks like this:

```
import java.io.*;
public class GameHelper {
    public String getUserInput(String promt){
        String inputLine = null;
        System.out.print(promt + " ");
        try {
            BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            if (inputLine.length() == 0) return null;
        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
        }
        return inputLine;
    }
}
```

But eclipse tells me the exception is never thrown from the try statement, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is simple. When the function reaches the end (getUserInput) and returns a value. That value is null because  `inputLine` is set to null and never set to anything else. Do what the other guy said (`inputLine = is.readLine();`) which reads the next line in the input (in this case the next input line). I am guessing that you are trying to get the next input and display it. This is what you want:

```
public String getUserInput(String promt){
String inputLine = null;
System.out.print(promt + " ");
try {
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        inputLine = is.readLine();
        if (inputLine.length() == 0) return null;
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e);
    }
    return inputLine;
}
```

The error probably was with the `inputLine.length()` because inputline is null and `inputLine.length()` would be an error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

 at GameHelper.getUserInput(GameHelper.java:10)
 at SimpleDotComTestDrive.main(SimpleDotComTestDrive.java:14)

Comment: I am guessing SimpleDotComTestDrive is the class you put in this question. Which is line 14?

Comment: String guess = helper.getUserInput("enter a number");

Comment: its strange because I have copied everything exactly from the book, just like it told me to do in this instance.

Comment: Commenting is allowed at about a reputation of 50 ;)

Comment: I see the problem now. I'll put it up

Answer (score 2):

The telling part of your code is when you create the new BufferedReader and check to see if the newly-read line is of length zero:

```
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        if (inputLine.length() == 0) return null;
```

Note that you haven't actually read in a line yet. Just add this line between the above two:

```
inputLine = is.readLine();
```

This will fix Eclipse's warning and ensure that you're actually reading a line from the input device.